# Python SQL query has the wrong type

Tags: python, database, types, database-connection, assertion

I want to execute a SQL Statement from my python program. For this I use the MySQLdb library. This is my code:

```
def execute(sql_statement):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("<DatabaseIP>", "<DatabaseUserName>", "<DatabasePassword>", "<DatabaseName>")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_statement)
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    db.close()
    return data

def look_up_user_id(username, password):
    print(type(username))
    print(type(password))
    sql_statement = "SELECT ID FROM user WHERE name = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'"
    print(sql_statement)
    return Database.execute(sql_statement)
```

This is the method in which the username and password are extracted from the request and the method that actually calls the Database class method.

```
@app.route('/auth', methods=['GET'])
def log_in():
    return AuthenticationManager.log_in(request.authorization.username, request.authorization.password)
```

```
def log_in(username, password):
    return Database.execute(SQLStatementBuilder.look_up_user_id(username, password))[0]
```

When I execute `print(look_up_user_id("me", "password"))` everything works as wanted and I get the ID of the user. But when I send a HTTP-Request to my Program with username and password in a basic authentication header, I get

```
File "<PythonPath>\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 208, in execute
   assert isinstance(query, (bytes, bytearray))
AssertionError
```

This is the method in which the Error is raised

```
    def execute(self, query, args=None):
        """Execute a query.

        query -- string, query to execute on server
        args -- optional sequence or mapping, parameters to use with query.

        Note: If args is a sequence, then %s must be used as the
        parameter placeholder in the query. If a mapping is used,
        %(key)s must be used as the placeholder.

        Returns integer represents rows affected, if any
        """
        while self.nextset():
            pass
        db = self._get_db()

        if isinstance(query, unicode):
            query = query.encode(db.encoding)

        if args is not None:
            if isinstance(args, dict):
                nargs = {}
                for key, item in args.items():
                    if isinstance(key, unicode):
                        key = key.encode(db.encoding)
                    nargs[key] = db.literal(item)
                args = nargs
            else:
                args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))
            try:
                query = query % args
            except TypeError as m:
                raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
        assert isinstance(query, (bytes, bytearray))
        res = self._query(query)
        return res
```

The two calls of print in the method `look_up_user_id`just return `<class 'str'>` in both test cases and for password and name.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: added method that raises Error

Comment: I added the methods and hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: It prints `<class 'str'>` . I added it now to the question aswell.

Comment: That is my own class, which at the moment only has the log_in  method in it you see in the block below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `lookup_user_id` is returning the result of `Database.execute(sql_statement)` and *that* result is being passed again to `Database.execute` in the return statement of `AuthorizationManager`.  To fix this, have `SQLStatementBuilder` return `sql_statement`.  Note also that `log_in` view should return a string or similar.

Also, consider executing SQL statements like this:

```
res = cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM user WHERE name = %s and password = %s""",
                     (username, password))
```

to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It now works and I will add your good advice to my code.